# Datatable is blocking events for button click on other pages except page 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with all the categories in my website. There is a function to delete a categori with AJAX while selecting a category to move the products(websites in my case) to another category. Here's how I do it:

```
$(".delete_category_instant").on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest("td").find(".editCategory").hide();
        $(this).closest("td").find(".selectCategoryToMove").removeClass("d-none");
      });

      $(".selectCategoryToMove").find(".submitSelection").on('click', function(event){
        $(this).closest("td").find(".selectCategoryToMove").addClass("d-none");
        $(this).closest("td").find(".confirmAction").removeClass("d-none");
        Toast.fire({
          icon: 'warning',
          title: 'Please confirm your action!'
        });
      });

      $(".confirmActionYes").on('click', function(event) {
        var cat_id = $(this).attr('category-id');
        var move_cat_id = $(this).closest("td").find("select").val();
        $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ url("administrator/delete/category/") }}',
            data: {
              id: cat_id,
              move_id: move_cat_id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.status == 1) {
                    Toast.fire({
                      icon: 'success',
                      title: 'Category deleted successfully!'
                    });
                    $this.parents('tr').remove();
                } else if(response.status == 2) {
                  Toast.fire({
                      icon: 'warning',
                      title: 'You are not allowed to do this action!'
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.fire({
                      icon: 'error',
                      title: 'Could not delete this category!<br/>Please try again later!'
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
      });

      $(".confirmActionNo").on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("d-none");
        $(this).parent().closest("td").find(".delete_category_instant").show();
        $(this).parent().closest("td").find(".editCategory").show();
      });
```

But that's working only on page 1 in the datatable. Inside other pages the button isn't even responding on click. What's the solution of that? Is that a common problem that I need to be aware of in the future?

Comment: You *must* use event delegation with datatables as it rebuilds the HTML each page / refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your event handlers are not connecting to new elements because the code that sets them up only runs once, on page load.  Can't tell from your example, but if that's the case you can use delegated listeners instead:

For example:

```
$(".confirmActionYes").on('click', function() {...})
```

becomes

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirmActionYes', function () {...})
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. But I'm confused about `$(".selectCategoryToMove").find(".submitSelection").on('click', function(event){`. What will that convert to?

Comment: I think `$(document).on('click', '.selectCategoryToMove .submitSelection', function () {...})` should work.  [More info](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I faced another problem. On other pages (again) except page 1, there is no action after the AJAX request. I can see the AJAX request is sent through the developers console but nothing happens. No category is deleted from the database, no row (in the datatable) is removed... But it's working on the first page.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: My bad. The error was in my back-end code. Thanks a ton @James!